# Search NSDictionary values with NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I've got a `NSDictionary` like so: object -> name , key -> phone number (array)

When the user searches, I want to create a new `NSDictionary` based on an Array with the search results, like: `@[@"Anna Haro",@"John Appleseed"];`

I know that `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys` is a built in function, but how do I create a new method `dictionaryWithKeysForValues`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I'm not a native english speaker I hope I've understood correctly what you are trying to achieve.

If I didn't misunderstood, what you are trying to achieve is if, for example, the search results array contain the strings `@"Anna Haro"` and `@"John Appleseed"`, you want to extract the corresponding keys from a given dictionary, and create a new dictionary that only holds the strings of the results array, and their corresponding keys from the dictionary, right?

If this is what you are trying to do, you can do the following:

```
{  
  // resultsArray will represent the NSArray that hold the search results  
  // originalDict will represent the NSDictionary you want to extract the keys from  

  NSMutableDictionary *resultsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  

  for (NSString *object in resultsArray) {  
      NSArray *keys = [originalDict allKeysForObject: object];  

      for (NSArray *key in keys) {  
          [resultsDict setObject: object forKey: key];  
        }  
    }  
}
```

In above code we are first creating `NSMutableDictionary` which will be our new dictionary from the results,
Then we are iterating thru each object of the search results array,
Then we call the `NSDictionary` method `allKeysForObject` on the original dictionary, for each object in the array, which creates an `NSArray` with all of the keys that corresponds to that object, so if you have several keys for an object, which in your specific case, if I understand correctly, is several phone numbers arrays for a person (although I guess it shouldn't happen), the array will hold all of them, and this is why our next step is to iterate thru that array as well,
And finally we are simply adding the value and key pair to the new dictionary.

Personally, I would set it the other way around,
I would set the phone numbers array as the object, and the person name as the key.
Make more sense to me, and I think it will be easier to access that way,
But that's your choice mate.

I hope that answered your question mate,
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! I've chosen this structure because the keys (phone numbers) are unique.